# Im having trouble with navbar in mobile for only my index page

Tags: css, mobile, navbar, responsive

**HTML file**

```html
<div class="header_section header_bg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="machines.html">Machines</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="work.html">Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

My website works great on desktop but I am having problem in mobile devices, where my navbar for my main menu is not working! Only for index page the other pages are working fine. I checked my index html code with the other pages and compared them, but nothing seems to look obvious. How should I solve this issue?

I was checking the `css` files and the `js` files but it all looks fine.

Comment: Pls provide css and javascript for closer look.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/zk1ilz02kv0qogonp60c6/h?rlkey=pgfcsk32smwmpwjf84iloof7d&dl=0 (this is the css)
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/77baw29qfrr4nf3oi85rk/h?rlkey=7f00p3idadaphin1tmg5irkyn&dl=0 (this is the js)

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided I cannot be sure but some problems i had in the past and how I fixed them...
First of all make sure to use the meta tag in the head to make the scaling responsive based on device:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Check for overlaping elements due to styling there is a possibility that some elements overlap your menu buttons so that they are not clickable and therefore you are clicking on other element causing unexpected behaviour.

ensure that the JavaScript and jQuery libraries are correctly linked in your index.html im asuming you are using jQuery since you are using data-toggle="collapse"

Since the issue is mobile-specific, inspect your CSS for any media queries that might be affecting the display or functionality of the navbar on mobile devices. You can use the developer tools to simulate mobile devices and see if any styles are being applied differently on the index

Comment: Yes, i am using jQuery. but as you mentioned my problem is in the CSS files i suppose since everything is working properly.

Comment: Check if any elements are overlaping with the menu and check the developer tools for mobile it is on the top left corner of the DevTools

Comment: Nothing seems to go wrong, my code is good. What is the issue that I am missing?